# Can't read keyboard input (SDL_GetKeyState)

Tags: sdl

I want to use SDL to check if a key is pressed.
I does not work. Also tried using Events but no SDL_KEYDOWN event is ever fired.
Visual C++ 2010 Express, Windows7.
Maybe i have set up SDL or the project wrong? How would i even know?

```
SDL_PumpEvents();
Uint8 *keys = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
if (keys[SDLK_RIGHT]) {         
    this->player.xf+=2.0f;      // never reached
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As is explained in the [documentation](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GetKeyState) `SDL_GetKeyState()` must be called only once per pointer.

`Uint8 *keys = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);` Allocates memory(!) and returns pointer to an array. This array is valid for the whole program duration and should not be freed.

Once this is called you have the pointer to your array and you can use it to check the state of keys with 
`keys[ SDLK_anykey ]`.

If you want to update the your `keys` array your simply call `SDL_PumpEvents();`

Comment: Thanks for this important info.
But i still don't get any keyboard input.
Note: I am using SDL only for the keyboard input. It's a Cocos2d-x application, which unfortunately has no keyboard support. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @KarlH. Dunno, I'm not familiar with Cocos, or how you implement all that. Check a tutorial for SDL to make sure you have your event set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but if it had a correct answer would have saved me some hours because of the same simple error I made.

`SDL_GetKeyState(NULL)` returns a const pointer array to a list of ***SCAN CODES***

`if (keys[SDLK_RIGHT])` in the OP's code above is a **KEYCODE**.

```
SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT = 79
```

`SDLK_RIGHT = SDL_SCANCODE_TO_KEYCODE(SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT)` //which is out of bounds on my system

Answer (score 0):

Usually `SDL_PollEvent` handles pulling the keystate, wich ultimately calls `SDL_PumpEvents()`.

It is true that you don't need to create a new pointer every loop itteration but your code should work just fine anyway. You would need to provide some additional details if we are to find the "source" of the problem.